# Python docx - 'Twips' object is not callable

Tags: python, docx

I have a simple script to generate a document using python docx. I can generate the document fine, but when I try to change anythig related to the document sections I get the error:

> ERROR - Error while processing: 'Twips' object is not callable

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
from docx.section import Section

doc = Document()
section = doc.sections[0]
section.page_width(Inches(5))
section.page_height(Inches(5))
```

I've tried different units and ways of calling the sections array. I'm assuming the created document already has a section by default, but I've also tried to call doc.add_section() before it and the same issue happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems it's not correct usage:

```
section.page_width(Inches(5))
section.page_height(Inches(5))
```

Instead try:

```
section.page_width = Inches(5)
section.page_height = Inches(5)
```